# Is it possible to create case insensitive Index via Room?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Currently, I have a Room entity which looks like

```
@Entity(
        tableName = "holiday_country",
        indices = {
                @Index(value = "code", unique = true)
        }
)
public class HolidayCountry
```

which is equivalent of having index

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_holiday_country_code` ON `holiday_country` (`code`)
```

However, I also need to have the following 2nd index as I will be performing case insensitive query sometimes.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_holiday_country_code_nocase` ON `holiday_country` (`code`  COLLATE NOCASE)
```

If that is so, how should such index be declared in Room entity?

Comment: If you want case insensitive queries, you can use `LOWER(column)` and compare it with `myString.toLower()`. Did you try that?

Comment: We prefer to use `COLLATE NOCASE` via DB instead of having to perform conversion at client side code.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, there are no options to define `COLLATE` on a column while creating an `Index`. By taking a look at the source code of `androidx.room.Index`, we can see that the only possible options are:

1. name of the index
2. option to define a unique index

**Index.java** *(comments were omitted due to conciseness)*

```java
package androidx.room;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface Index {
   
    String[] value();

    String name() default "";

    boolean unique() default false;
}
```

So, the only possible way in `Room`, is to define the `COLLATE` in the table creation statement:

```java
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.Index;

@Entity(
    tableName = "holiday_country",
    indices = {
        @Index(value = "code", unique = true)
    }
)
public class HolidayCountry {
        
    @ColumnInfo(name = "code", collate = ColumnInfo.NOCASE) 
    public String code;
        
    // Other fields ...
}
```